# How to add the Trend Line in Salesforce Line Chart Report

Tags: report-chart

I have created the report to know the record count based on the created date. I have created the report but unable to add the trend line in the line chart.

Comment: What format is your base report as in is it a tabular, summary (or) matrix?

Comment: Matrix format. Is there any possible to create the formula filed for the trend line calculation?

Comment: When you say you are unable to add trend line what do you see for X and Y values in your chart

Comment: x axis is created date and y axis is the record count

Comment: What do you want to see in the x-axis?

Comment: i have created the chart and it will disply the bottom created date and corss line is record count i want to add trend line.

Comment: did you group by any data or summarize any column in your base report?

Comment: No. i didnt group. I jsut create matrix reprot and add once chart for this. i want to visible the trend line in that cahrt.

Comment: Group by a specific column and make it the y-axis you should see some data plot.

Comment: IS this possible in vf page chart?